# How to model a global resource in a REST API?

Tags: api, rest, model

REST seems to focus most on collections of resources -- lists of things.  How should one model something that exists exactly once in a system?  And more specifically something very simple.  Suppose the modeled system is a classroom, which has  students, 1 teacher, and a door that is either open or closed.  How would one model the door? I'm thinking it would be something like the following:

```
GET and POST operations are supported.
GET https://<ipaddress>/classroom/door_status
    Returns 200 if successful, with a response containing:
        DoorStatus - String - Value of door status, either "Open" or "Closed"
POST https://<ipaddress>/classroom/door_status
    Specify the attribute of:
        DoorStatus - String - Value of desired door status, "Open" or "Closed"
    Returns 201 if the status was successfully modified.
```

DELETE would always fail.

A classroom could of course have multiple doors, but bear with me for the moment.  And of course a building with classrooms often has multiple classrooms.  Again bear with me.

Next, we might add a light_status resource for the classroom.  Given this is likely, should we start with a "global_properties" resource, which would have DoorStatus and LightStatus properties instead.

Thanks for suggestions, help, or (especially) examples.  ...Alan

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything in REST that makes single instance entities illegal or undesirable. That said, in your particular example, you need to evaluate if the door and the light:

1. Are their own entities related but otherwise independent from the class, **OR**
2. Are just attributes or contained objects of the class without their own identity and whose existence depends on the existence of the class

the second option is the one that seems more reasonable to me. If we accept it, then you can return the light and door status as part of the class properties:

```
GET /class -- Returns the class attributes, including light and door status
PUT /class -- updates class attributes, including light and door status
```